# hector_quadrotor not listening to teleop_twist_keyboard

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using `hector_quadrotor`, and am trying to get a simple quadrotor moving in it using my keyboard.

I run the demo using `roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo outdoor_flight_gazebo.launch` and it gives out a few messages which can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/ds5z8VJp) (There are no errors, but a few warnings are there)

Then I run `rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py` which gives out the following [output](http://pastebin.com/wKERiyFf)

When i press u,i,o,j,k,l,m ... nothing happens

My understanding is that they send/recv messages on `/cmd_vel` to talk to each other. So, I read that I can see that using `rostopic info /cmd_vel` and i get :

```
Type: geometry_msgs/Twist

Publishers: 
 * /teleop_twist_keyboard (http://ajk-VPCSB38GG:49644/)

Subscribers: 
 * /gazebo (http://ajk-VPCSB38GG:46506/)
```

So, it seems both are connected to the node, and `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` gives:

```
$ rostopic echo /cmd_vel
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
linear: 
  x: 0.5
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 1.0
---
```

when I press `u` in the `teleop_twist_keyboard`. So, it seems to be sending, but the `hector_quadrotor_demo` isn't catching it.

A bit more info :
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo. I installed all packages using the Ubuntu ppa for ROS and apt-get.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209186/hector_quadrotor-not-listening-to-teleop_twist_keyboard/) by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22426/abdealijk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [creative_cimmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/22559/creative_cimmons/) on 2015-06-06**:
Yeah, even I am facing the same issue!!!

**Comment by [c123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22663/c123/) on 2015-06-07**:
Same for myself.

**Comment by [creative_cimmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/22559/creative_cimmons/) on 2015-06-09**:
[ INFO] [1433906927.086001345, 0.001000000]: imu plugin missing , defaults to 0s
[ INFO] [1433906927.086072918, 0.001000000]: imu plugin missing , defaults to 0s

I guess the problem is because of missing imu plugin,, could anybody debug that!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, as there has been no answer - I am posting the solution I found myself...
It seems the
We wrote a code to `teleop_twist_keyboard` doesn't give the quadrotor linear z velocity to go upward. So, if you start the quadrotor at a height (let's say 1000 m) ... while it falls down you can move left/right and so on.

We wrote our own [module](https://github.com/Quadrotor-RL/quadrotor_controller/tree/79e4ee4dd8b05cb1cc874c9b02d0af727f49963b) to test it out which works. Here's the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import Tkinter as tk
import threading
import thread
import time
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import pygame, sys

def talker():
    global clock

    pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('controller', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        msg = Twist()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        array = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if array[pygame.K_UP]:
            msg.linear.z = 1;
        elif array[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            msg.linear.z = -1;
        
        if array[pygame.K_w]:
            msg.linear.y = 1;
        elif array[pygame.K_s]:
            msg.linear.y = -1;
        
        if array[pygame.K_d]:
            msg.linear.x = 1;
        elif array[pygame.K_a]:
            msg.linear.x = -1;

        rospy.loginfo(msg)
        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()
    

pygame.init()
size = [100, 100]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # threading.Thread(target=tk_func())    
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

Originally posted by [AbdealiJK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22426/abdealijk/) with karma: 98 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And [here](https://github.com/CreativeCimmons/Cloud_Drone/tree/master/hector_quadrotor_kbdcontroller) is the link to cpp version.

I am not sure about the 1000 m initialization,, I don't think that is required

---

Originally posted by [creative_cimmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/22559/creative_cimmons/) with karma: 47 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2